# How can I negate part of a class in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to negate part of a class in a regular expression. Let's say we have an expression accepting repeated big or small letters from a to z.

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

How can I negate for example `H` letter?

I've tried this `[a-zA-Z^H]+` but [it doesn't block H](https://regex101.com/r/sE6tH0/1).

I know we can do it otherwise, but I search for a general rule to negate inside of a class.

I use JavaScript flavor of regex.

**UPDATE**

Here's the more specific example. Here's the expression: `[\w\-\–]`. In .NET flavor it accepts unicode characters, but in JavaScript flavor it doesn't. There's a trick however to allow the expression to accept unicode chars too, `\w` must be replaced with this expression `([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)`.

The problem is - it can't be nested inside first expression (`[\w\-\–]`). That's why I'm asking how to make a negation of a part of a class.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Guys, he knows he can do it otherwise.

Comment: @Sobrique In particular I want eliminate `(|)` part from this expression `([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+`. I have some expression which I want to transform and don't want to dig into it to much. It has multiple `\w` inside. In .NET flavor `\w` allows unicode characters, but not in JavaScript. I'm going to adapt this old regex to JS. The problem is I have some `\w`'s inside clases and can't simply replace them with my `([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)` expression because `(|)` is not allowed in classes. So I need to find alternate way to have alternative inside classes.

Comment: First thing you should add `Javascript` tag to your question. Then you should add some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: When you use `^` inside of a class it's for whole class and not single character. You will have to go around like this `[a-zA-GI-Z]+` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/sE6tH0/3)

Comment: Second thing, you should provide an example of what you want, otherwise we are blindly guessing stuff. Third, make clear what the heck you want!

Comment: "So I need to find alternate way to have alternative inside classes." -> "So I need to find alternate way to use negation inside classes."

Comment: Will [`((?:[^\x00-\x7F]|[\w\-\–])+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rO4jD0/2) work for you?

Comment: You may use `((?!H)(?:[^\x00-\x7F]|[\w-–]))+`.

Comment: You cannot get rid of the `|` here in JS because the first part contains a negation of the second part. You cannot negated something and accept something with one and the same pattern. You could achieve that with a lookahead as Jakub points out if you have a positive character class. Note that `[^\x00-\x7F]` matches all non-ASCII symbols, not only *letters*.

Comment: @anubhava This is it!

Comment: @Landeeyo: If you want to get rid of `|`, you can match any character that is not an ASCII that is not from the `[\w-]` range: [`(?:(?!(?![\w-])[\x00-\x7F]).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/iU6dS7/3). En-dash can be safely removed since it will be matched with `.` restricted that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Translating my comment into an answer*. Here is a regex that you can use for negating certain character or range:

```
/((?:[^\x00-\x7F]|[-\w–])+)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO4jD0/4)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use class subtraction

`[a-zA-Z--[H]]`

For engines that don't support character class subtraction (javascript) you can simply use a negative lookahead.

`((?![H])[a-zA-Z])+`

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/sE6tH0/6

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction_workaround

Comment: This won't avoid `H`. The first part `(?![H])` will look for `H` but won't capture it, but second part `[a-zA-Z]+` will capture `H` anyways. [See this](https://regex101.com/r/sE6tH0/5)

Comment: Forgot brackets, fixed

Comment: *Normally* means *in .NET* here. In Java, it would look different.